# Python - Issue when printing multiple contents in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I've got a little bit of code of a very basic account logging in system. The issue is that I have three parts to one account: the `uname`, `upass` and then `bal`. All worked fine until I introduced the **`bal`**.

I'm very amateur with Python and cannot figure out how to fix it. My intentions are to have 3 parts to every account I add, the username, password and then account balance but as of now I've written the code as logical as possible with my knowledge for it to work but it just doesn't seem to print or function the balance / **`bal`** very well.

Code:

```
class Login:
    def __init__(self):
        self.users = {}

    def addUser(self, uname, upass, bal):
        self.users[uname] = upass, bal;

    def login(self):
        userNameInput = input("Username: ")
        userPassInput = input("Password: ")
        if userNameInput in self.users:
            if userPassInput in self.users[userNameInput]:
                print("Access Granted!")
                self.access(userNameInput)

        else:
            print("Access Denied!")
            return self.login()

    def access(self, uname, bal):
        print("Welcome, "+uname+"!"+bal)

def main():

    mylogin = Login()
    mylogin.addUser("u123", "p123", 123)
    mylogin.login()

main()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tom\Desktop\test.py", line 29, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Tom\Desktop\test.py", line 27, in main
    mylogin.login()
  File "C:\Users\Tom\Desktop\test.py", line 14, in login
    self.access(userNameInput)
TypeError: access() missing 1 required positional argument: 'bal'
```

Extra minor question:
For the part "Def access", the part of `uname` for some reason can be named ANYTHING yet still print the actual name of the account when logged in. It makes no sense to me why that part works perfect with a completely different name.

Comment: i think you forgot to pass bal parameter in access function

Comment: @KalyanReddy Sorry, should have stated I tried that. It simply then gives me a new error: TypeError: access() missing 1 required positional argument: 'bal'

Comment: if you add a parameter bal, then you should send it in the function call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `access` method takes `bal` as an argument, but you don't pass the `bal` when you call `self.access(userNameInput)`. You could just get the `bal` in the `access` method and remove the `bal` parameter.

Also, you can't concatenate strings and ints here: `print("Welcome, "+uname+"!"+bal)`. Just use `str.format` instead.

```
class Login:

    def __init__(self):
        self.users = {}

    def addUser(self, uname, upass, bal):
        self.users[uname] = upass, bal

    def login(self):
        userNameInput = input("Username: ")
        userPassInput = input("Password: ")
        if userNameInput in self.users:
            if userPassInput in self.users[userNameInput]:
                print("Access Granted!")
                self.access(userNameInput)
        else:
            print("Access Denied!")
            # You shouldn't recurse here and use a loop instead.
            # Python has a recursion limit.
            return self.login()

    # Remove the `bal` parameter.
    def access(self, uname):
        # Get the bal out of the self.users dict.
        bal = self.users[uname][1]
        print("Welcome, {}!{}".format(uname, bal))

def main():
    mylogin = Login()
    mylogin.addUser("u123", "p123", 123)
    mylogin.login()

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

`bal` has never been saved under that name. Use `str(self.users[uname][1])` instead.

Answering the second question, you simply print the value of the parameter without doing any checks. Why do you expect it to fail? But it will fail when you implement the change suggested in the first part of this answer.